# drag&drop text from iframe to main window doesn't drop the text

Tags: html, macos, iframe

I would like to drag&drop text from iframe to input on OSX, but it doesn't work.

```html
<input />
<iframe
   src="https://react-hooks.org/"
   title="inline browser"
></iframe>
<span>adasdasas</span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a CORS issue, see this code:

```
<input />
<iframe
   src="https://react-hooks.org/"
   title="inline browser"
></iframe>
<iframe id="myframe"></iframe>

<script>
var ifrm = document.getElementById('myframe');
ifrm = ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument.document || ifrm.contentDocument;
ifrm.document.open();
ifrm.document.write('Hello World!');
ifrm.document.close();
</script>
<span>adasdasas</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lqjvc6p/

In my tests, I had no difficulty while dragging and dropping from `#myframe` into the `input`, since it's using the same origin, while doing the same from your `iframe`, that has a different origin proved to be impossible. You could make your server act as a proxy to work around the issue, that is, request to the target on server-side and output the content as the content of an `iframe`. That should work, but you will have difficulty with coping the js, css and img content of the original.